# Artifacts on IE10 using CSS3 perspective transform

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10, css-transforms, artifacts

I'm experiencing an issue on Internet Explorer 10 when using CSS transform property to change the 3D perspective.

Random artifacts appear on the edge of some elements contained in the element with the perspective applied.

I've created a simple fiddle to demonstrate the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/b9ztC/

To reproduce, just open the fiddle and try to select, click or play around with the text, this results in the following artifacts appearing/disappearing around the paragraph element:

[image: IE10 perspective transform artifacts]

More lines and artifacts appear in more complex scenarios, and the cause seems to be the following line of css:

```
transform: perspective(800px);
```

The only ways to solve the issue seem to be:

- not to have the perspective applied to the element
- setting the transform perspective to `0px`
- use `perspective: 800px`, instead of `transform: perspective(800px)`

The last one seems an easy solution but it doesn't work well in some scenarios, the following 3D flipping card demo for example (which has the same artifacts problem on the back of the card using IE10) doesn't play well when applying the perspective property separately from the rotation transform: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/css3-3d-card.html

Have anyone experienced this issue? Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

I'd also like to know if this happens on every machine or it can be an hardware-related issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing more or less the same issue, though only on the left side of the div, it changes depending on the transform. It seems to be the background bleeding through at the edges of the line.

I'm on Windows 7 x64 with an Radeon HD 4670 (Catalyst 13.1), using IE 10.0.9200.16686 (KB2870699).

The only practical workaround I've found so far is to apply the padding on the inner element, ie on the `p` instead of on the `div`. However I'm not sure whether the padding is actually the trigger, so this might not be applicable in other situations.